# Jenkins Build logs

Tags: maven, jenkins

Is there in any way to get the list of files and line number which are causing build failure in Jenkins?

Scenario:
My requirement is to get the list of files and their line number which are causing build failure and i am using Jenkins with maven plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Warnings Plugin.

Add a Post-Build step to scan for compiler warnings.